# Why I can't switch from super user to regular user with su username?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to switch to normal user but it doesn't work
I just want a dollar sign instead of the hash...

```
root@username:~# su username
No passwd entry for user 'username'
```

I'm on Windows on Ubuntu bash and next to the logo (up right) I still see `root@username~`. And if I close/open I get again `root@username~#`.

Comment: Have you try `su - username`

Comment: Does the user `username` exist?

Comment: The purpose of `su` is to change your id (in this case from 0 to X), the numerical ID is in `/etc/passwd` (or network directory like NIS or AD). if system cannot find a conversion from `username` to a numerical uid, it can't su.

Comment: Various things not in the question are buried in answer comments, including the fact that this is _not Linux_ despite the tag and the questioner is looking at window titles on Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 4):

> `No passwd entry for user 'username'`

This happens when the user doesn't exist. 
To resolve it, you first need to create a user:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash toto
```

This will create a user named *toto* with his home directory, and with **BASH** as its shell.

Then you can do your command: **`su toto`**. But the command you would want to use is:

**`su - toto`**

With `su - toto` you load the environment of the user, like the home directory, etc. with only `su toto`you do not and you keep the previous user's environment. Which isn't what you would want (I think)

Comment: Can you explain why that would be the 'normal' command?

Comment: That would be the _normal_ command because with `su - ` you load the environment of the user, like the home directory, etc. with only `su` you do not. This isn't the topic here, so I didn't think of including this explaination here. Should I ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Because you mention it in your answer, it might be good to add, yes. Or remove the part about the 'normal' command.

Comment: @jayooin Thanks for the response. I did... and now I get just a $. Is this normal? Shouldn't it be something like: username@laptopname:~$   Note: I'm on Windows on Ubuntu bash and next to the logo (up right) I still see root@username~  . And if I close/open I get again root@username~#

Comment: @FotisTsakiris, that's because when you open the shell, in your terminal, it opens the shell as root. You will need to do `su - username` each time. If you want to log in as another user, you need to reboot your machine. Or at least log out. Concerning the `$` without the `username@laptopname:~$`, that is because it is using `sh` and not `bash`. I'll edit my answer to make it use bash.

Comment: @jayooin Thanks again. I did `useradd -m -s /bin/bash toto` and then `su - toto` and now I get `toto@superuser:~$` I'm not sure about the `superuser` though. What is that after the `@`? .  Anyways it's fully functioning now. Thanks a lot! **:)** . Pls forgive me for the mess. I'm sorry.